# My list won't update event after it's index has

Tags: flutter, dart

Ok I'm quite new to flutter and I've tried a  bunch of thing for this but I think I'm not tackling the issue with the right idea.
So I'm asking here, how can I change the index in my list when I change page in my carousel.
I switched to a StatefulWidget just so I could use setState() but it didn't change anything, I think I might have to use some sort of notifiers and all but I've almost never used them so I don't know how to implement them here

```
Column (
  children: [
     CarouselSlider(
        items: myBoards,
        options: CarouselOptions(
           enableInfiniteScroll: false,
           height: 80,
           viewportFraction: 0.8,
           initialPage: 0,
           reverse: false,
           enlargeCenterPage: true,
           onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                 _currentIndex = index;
              });
           },
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        )
     ),
     Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
        child: CropListView(Controller: Controller,documents: documents, index: _currentIndex),
     ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Have you verified onPageChanged is getting called and index is different from previous value?

Comment: Yes I did, everything works fine it's just that the listView doesn't update